# Avoid widening while inferring generic types

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

Take this example function

```
type Decoder<A, B> = (v: A) => B 

declare function test<Values, D extends Decoder<Values, unknown>>(options: {
    values: Values,
    decoder: D,
    onDecoded: (decodedValue: ReturnType<D>) => unknown
}): void;
```

The idea is that `onDecoded` gets in input the value computed by `decoder`. However:

```
test({
    values: { a: "" },
    decoder: values => values.a.length,
    onDecoded: decodedValue => {
        decodedValue // unknown
    }
})
```

Strangely enough, if I don't use `values` in the definition of `decoder` then `decodedValue` has the correct type

```
test({
    values: { a: "" },
    decoder: () => 42,
    onDecoded: decodedValue => {
        decodedValue // number
    }
})
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDGB7AJhATgHgIIBooCEA+KAXigAoA3ALiiwEpTj8oBYAKA9XgBsBDNNABmAVwB28YAEtEYqMAgBnYBgBqfHiKV4YUCAA8FY5ItgIU6NRq2K84gNZjEAdzGFC5RGGmzFtAN4cUMFQlNZKtOqa2kEh3BZotDA4scGycEioyLTk8VlRWrQAShDAImhiACrgEBgwhIwkxA5OrhwAvvS0lIhSyADcHBwKyuSB7CGh4X5Q-lB8tABEi1DtKRNx5qiJU9GmTbs2AHR8RzwQYgDmwAAW65PpWxDZUHnPBUpMs6mTr0-IH1MAHogVAWi4xD92h16EN2CNgGMfmE9gF5ksVmsfm8duRGsQACwAJnuIUemWetDeAOmX3Gv02FJpeygIKgYhEAFsAEboKEwjhAA) with the same example

Is there a way to make the original example work?

Comment: Even weirder (to me), `decodedValue`'s type changes to `number` if you just change `decoder` to `decoder: (values) => 42`. Just *declaring* the parameter, without even using it, changes things.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question. It's true that `D` extends `Decoder<Values, unknown>` but it's actual type is inferred to be `Decoder<Values, number>`, so I would expect `ReturnType<D>` to result in `number`. Isn't that a fair assumption?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still newish to the `unknown` type but I think I get it. Thanks.

Comment: you can replace anything there, really. `unknown` is just a reasonable upper bound for this case, but ideally I would expect it to never be inferred

Comment: and yes, I've noticed that behavior too. It seems that just adding the parameter changes the type inference algorithm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler gives up before it can infer everything.  You've got a single object from which the compiler needs to infer two type parameters, but it can't do it all at once.

First let me refactor your signature to a nearly equivalent version that might be more straightforward to analyze:

```
declare function test<A, B>(options: {
    values: A,
    decoder: (a: A) => B,
    onDecoded: (b: B) => unknown
}): void;
```

This has the same inference issue as your version, but it's a little easier to talk about the types.  Anyway, the compiler needs to infer `A` and `B` from the `options` value passend you want to infer `A` and `B` from it.  It can infer `A` from the type of `values`, but it probably can't infer `B` unless the implementation of `decoder` happens not to depend on `A`, so it fails.

The details of type inference aren't something I'm an expert on.  But if there is a canonical answer to this question, it's at [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) which uses a very similar data structure and runs into the same problem.  This is classified as a design limitation in TypeScript, so there's probably no way to fix this without altering your `test` function or the way you call it.

---

Altering the way you call it would involve giving enough type info to the compiler to allow it to work.  For example, If you annotate the type of `decoder`'s input argument when you call it, you're fine:

```
test({
    values: { a: "" },
    decoder: (values: { a: string }) => values.a.length, // annotate
    onDecoded: decodedValues => {
        decodedValues // number
    }
})
```

Or you can change how `test()` is defined.  One suggestion I have is to split the `options` object out into separate parameters.  The compiler is a little more willing to spend multiple inference passes for different function parameters than it is for a single parameter.  Maybe like this:

```
declare function test2<A, B>(values: A,
    decoder: (a: A) => B,
    onDecoded: (b: B) => unknown
): void;

test2(
    { a: "" },
    values => values.a.length,
    decodedValues => {
        decodedValues // number
    }
)

test2({ a: "" },
    () => 42,
    decodedValues => {
        decodedValues // number
    }
)
```

Those inferences work exactly as you want, and you can probably rewrite them using `D` and `ReturnType` if you must.

---

Which way you go is up to you I guess.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAeAQQBp4AhAPgAocAHbPIgLngG8BYAKHhD4ANygRkxLlQHD4oMDlAwuDKNICU8ALx1alWcLwARcEpDBVAIy40tu+GgDWqHAHdUAgL4auInFjAANwCAoQkDHyCwmISUjzw6vAARMnwXgbRQgrmKqLikkQ6erGFAHRQZRAgqADmGAAWmXImZqCW8m0WAGoFxMU8hnLZXcC9cUUA9JOOqC7unlnp3hqyYcQYkUP5E1zciVyp6c3COcqqpfH7SSQwWHXp9iV9RBVVNfVN262K7VxnPReAyiw1Oo3GhXg03gqGQAFsrCAYNsvCtQvx1hEQTEXnsDik0hltgC8gwnvAACwAJhOQh+5g6ALGQIc2NBTIh-WhsIRSJRaIx-AU0DgSDQmFw+HCGCpFGo9AYl048BkSxJqiS5HJNFp8Hpf3gDBstHJzlcHgEvlEAWC6OlVIY22uh0JuqVAyVb2qdUauo5LL0bOG-omUJmPMRyKWqP4q0F9si+KORKWZIG1L94IDgyWchDkO58Mj-NjAiAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and for the pointer to the GitHub issue. I actually ended up with a very similar workaround (separate positional parameters) but now it’s much clearer why it works!