# Generic type inferred from wrong usage

Tags: typescript, generics

As I understand, TS prefers direct type usages over "boxed" ones (e.g. in function) to infer a generic type from.

```js
type Props<O, V> = {
  options: O[]
  getOptionValue: (o: O) => V
  value?: V
  onChange?: (v: V, o: O) => void
}
```

In this snippet type `V` is inferred from `value` field which is undesirable since `value` property is optional. Can I somehow force generic type inference to rely on `getOptionValue` property?

[Sandbox example](https://tsplay.dev/4w16XN) where if no `value` passed to a component its `onChange` argument `v` becomes `unknown`

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600241/avoid-widening-while-inferring-generic-types).  The compiler doesn't make multiple inference passes when trying to infer the types of a single object.

My workaround suggestion here would be the same as there: split your function into multiple parameters instead of a single parameter with multiple properties.  You could even make a helper function like this:

```
const props = <O, V>(
    options: O[],
    getOptionValue: (o: O) => V,
    value?: V,
    onChange?: (v: V, o: O) => void
): Props<O, V> => ({ options, getOptionValue, onChange })
```

And then use it:

```
const theProps = props(
    [""],
    (o) => "test",
    undefined,
    (v, o) => v.length < o.length
);
```

Here you can see that `O` and `V` are properly inferred to be `string` and `v` is not `unknown` in the `onChange` callback.  You can use also this with JSX via spread:

```
const c = <C {...theProps} />;
```

It's not perfect, since you're getting inference in exchange for a multi-step jsx element creation.  But it does work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCzAVwDsNgJa4BhAHgHkAaOANQD4AFGBxgAzgC44ABVFjOPAQEo4AbwpxNcIjGpRmbfmwD0-OBQC+FCjACeYJDLkK+ZgLxqNWiGBiNaknAcANoAul6aAOZIMBy+-rwoADbUSFKCEFIcKm5mvBFwAG7JqQD8UvnkWnBMLAAWKLTR5XCChRU8mUE5ZoUQwAAmltbkaExi8CI+YnAeLgKCBT5+41lhXAXRsfFMiSlprV3Zs3kbVVrF+y28Z9W1DU1ILW0dNVk9Rf1D5EpSstPzdxmQSqGo7AI8LZxFa0PapTq0eqNaJwCxKEZjALwGB1JD-cSzOBTcSLc6aYIAIgpoVuWgyHwpMCQEwptM0dAGSEwwFoSAGbNahU6H0KADokkgmji4GwauLJZEcRQlABuDHjeBoQlsFhqUX6nF4uQWOCmNXkIA)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, because even if you remove the `value` property entirely typescript still won't use `getOptionValue` to infer the type.

```
function C<O, V>(props: {
    options: O[]
    getOptionValue: (o: O) => V
    onChange?: (v: V, o: O) => void
}) {}

C({
    options: [""],
    getOptionValue: (o) => "test",
    onChange: (v, o) => v.test // error: v is STILL 'unknown'
})
```

Comment: It's true there's something else going on here, but I don't think this answers the implied question "how can I make V properly inferred?"

Comment: @AlexWayne When I wrote I don't think so, I meant I don't think it's possible.

Comment: This answers my question since somehow I came to the conclusion that w/o `value` prop it infers correctly. I'll wait a bit just in case if someone comes up with any workaround to get things inferred